# How to calculate the minimum number of person present during two times

Tags: algorithm, time

I'm going to be as clear as I can.

I have an event that have two times, start and end. (Times are in 24h format)
For example, this event starts at 8, and finishes at 12.

With this event, I have a list of person with their work schedule.
Here's an example :

- Person 1 : From 8:00 to 10:00
- Person 2 : From 10:00 to 12:00
- Person 3 : From 6:00 to 15:00
- Person 4 : From 8:00 to 9:00
- Person 5 : From 9:30 to 12:00

Now, I need to know how many people, at minimum, I have through the whole event.

In my case, it will be **2**, because :

- Person 1 & Person 2 complement each other
- Person 3 will always be present
- There is a gasp between person 4 & 5, between 9:00 and 9:30, so during this time, no one between Person 4 & 5 will be present.

If I explain this with times :

- From 8:00 to 9:00 : Person 1, 3, 4
- From 9:00 to 9:30 : Person 1, 3
- From 9:30 to 10:00 : Person 1, 3, 5
- From 10:00 to 12:00 : Person 2, 3, 5

Most of the time, the event will have 3 person, but the lowest if 2.

How can I get this number using an algorithm, I can't make my mind with this.

I thought about converting the time in minutes (I won't go under the minute), set the range at the event times (from 8*60 to 12*60), and add each person presence as a new range, and then count for each minutes, how many slice there is (1 slice = 1 person). But I feel this isn't efficient, because I will have to count the slices for 4*60 minutes :/ (from 8 -> 12).

How would you do ?

Comment: Is the smallest increment of time 1 minute? If it is smaller than that, counting the slices may not even work, because you may have to account for seconds.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the start and end times for person number `i`, and name them `s_i` and `e_i`.

Put all of these in a list, `times`. Then do the following:

```
# start_time contains the start time of the event
# end_time contains the start time of the event
sort(times) # When doing this sort, make sure that if a s_i
            # is at the same time as a e_j, put the s_i first.

current_number = number of people who're there at start_time
remove all times that match start_time from times

minimum_number = current_number

for time in times:
    if time is an s_i: current_number += 1

    if time is an e_i:
        current_number -= 1
        if current_number < minimum_number and time < end_time:
            minimum_number = current_number
```

The running time for this is found as follows:

Let `n` be the number of people.

We spend `O(n lg n)` time doing the sorting, as we only have `2n` times to sort.

We then spend `O(n)` time iterating through the times, doing constant work.

Overall, `O(n lg n)`. Note that this running time is completely independent of how large an interval of time it spans over, and is only dependent on how many people you're dealing with.

This is a form of [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). We sweep through the times, only stopping at the points of interest (the `s_i` and `e_i`s.)

Note, the reason we sort the `s_i`s before `e_j`s in case of a tie, is as follows:

If we don't, then imagine we have two people: Bob is here from 8-10, Alice is here from 10-12. We might then, if we don't do careful sorting, get the following list of times:

```
times = [(s_Bob, 8), (e_Bob, 10), (s_Alice, 10), (e_Alice, 12)]
```

If we sort it like this, then it looks like there are no people left after Bob leaves at 10. However, Alice is there, since she arrives at the same time. Thus, to prevent this, we sort it such that starting times are before ending times, in case of a tie:

```
times = [(s_Bob, 8), (s_Alice, 10), (e_Bob, 10), (e_Alice, 12)]
```

Comment: Finally, I have to loop through all the minutes from start to end ?

Comment: @CyrilN.: You don't have to, no. The only times the number of people can change is when a person comes or leaves. Thus we only need to look at those times.

Comment: Hum I think I understand you idea. Finally, I only have to check at start & end for each times of persons ? (`if time is an s_i`, what do you mean by `an` ? equals ? or did you meant `in`?)

Comment: @CyrilN.: We have two kinds of times. Starting times and ending times. by "`if time is an s_i`", I mean: If `time` is a starting time.

Comment: Yeah ok, great, this is perfect! Thanks for you idea!

Comment: The problem with this implementation (if I understood correctly) is that you have two entries for each person : start & end. So you end up with +1, -1 for each person => You will always have 0 at the minimum number :/

Comment: @CyrilN. I believe Sebastian Paaske Torhol wants you to be updating the minimum number after processing each time, not each person.

Comment: If we take the last code part : `times = [(s_Bob, 8), (s_Alice, 10), (e_Bob, 10), (e_Alice, 12)]`. At start, we have +1 (+Bob), at 10 we have +1, then -1 (+Alice, -Bob), and at 12, we have -1 (-Alice) = 0.

Comment: So it seems like a special check would need to be made for the very last removal (assuming when the last person leaves is meant to be the end of the event).

Comment: @CyrilN.: Indeed. Special care need to be taken with the start and end times. I've updated the condition on e_i case to take care of this.

Comment: I improved a bit : Instead of testing if `time < end_time`, I exclude from the array `times` all entries that have `end_time >= event time`. That mean I will only loop on the array `times` if there is times inside the `start&end` of the event. If there isn't, I won't loop and get directly `current_number` as `minimum_number`.

Answer (score 0):

quick answer, perhaps update the number of people whenever someone starts/finishes work?

For example, at t0 you set it up to know who's there. Every next minute, or better, for every leave/entry date (sorted) note the new number of present people.

Comment: So your telling me to count for every minutes ?

Comment: for every entry/leave event, but I guess the question is now throughly answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many persons in your event you could go and do something like

```
minimum -> infinity
for each person in persons do:
    intersections -> 0
    for each other person in persons do:
        if other person start time <= person start time
            if other person end time >= person start time
                intersections++
        else if other person start time < person end time
            intersections++
    if intersections < minimum
        minimum = intersections
```

Answer (score 0):

hauron's answer helped me create this solution.

Here is psuedo code, since there is no language tag.

Have a sorted list of start times, and a sorted list of end times
Start a counter for current people at zero
Also have a counter for minimum people at a positive infinity
Have the most recent time as the initial time of the event

Go through the lists together, picking the sooner of the first start time and first end time

If the sooner is a start time, increment the counter and remove the first start time
Else the sooner is an end time, decrement the counter and remove the first end time

If the just used time is not the same as the most recent time, check the minimum people counter (For example, if 3 people enter at once, wait to update the minimum people counter until processing all three people) 
If the current people is smaller than the minimum people, set the minimum people as the current people

Update the most recent time
Repeat until both lists are empty

The minimum people counter should have your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your algorithm should be designed like this:

- From 8:00 : Person 1, 3, 4
- From 9:00 : Person 1, 3
- From 9:30 : Person 1, 3, 5
- From 10:00 : Person 2, 3, 5

First add the start and end times of the event to a *set*
Next, iterate through your members building a *set* of start and end times (set prevents duplicates).
Then iterate through the items in the set and check each member against each element in the set to see if his start time is >= and end time is > then the item in the set. Have a counter for the internal iteration to keep track of the number of people at a given time, and have a variable outside both iterations that keeps track of the minimum number of people at a given time. In pseudocode:

```
var set : set
var event_start : time = 8:00
var event_end : time = 12:00
set.add(event_start)
foreach(person in people)
    set.add(person.start)
    set.add(person.end)
var min : int = people.size
var time_of_min : time
foreach time in set
    var num_people : int = 0
    foreach person in people
        if person.start >= time && person.end > time
            num_people++
    if num_people < min
        min = num_people
        time_of_min = time
// Handle the special case of the ending time
var num_people_at_end : int = 0
foreach person in people
    if person.end == event_end
        num_people_at_end++
if num_people_at_end < min
    min = num_people_at_end
    time_of_min = event_end
```